# ATK4 How OneToMany retion can be used with multiselect?

Tags: mysql, atk4

I have 2 MySQL DB tables called roles (representing user access role) and modules (representing allowed modules per role). Each role can have many modules and each module can have many roles.

I want to add a crud representing roles table with a multiselect field allowing to select all related modules. What is the best way to do that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple solutions for this.

**First one** - use User CRUD with expander with Roles (should work):

```
$crud = $this->add('CRUD');
$crud->setModel('User');

if (! $crud->isEditing()) {
    // add subCRUD
    $sub_crud = $crud->addRef('UserRole', array(
        'extra_fields' => array('role'),
        'view_options' => array('entity_name' => 'Role'),
        'label' => 'Roles'
    ));
}
```

**Second one** - use Grid with Roles + grid->addSelectable($fields) (not tested, but just to give you idea):

```
$grid = $this->add('Grid');
$grid->setModel('UserRole');
$grid->addSelectable('selected');
```

**Third one** - use two lists with roles (available roles and associated roles) and some buttons to "move" role from one list to another.
Something like this: (can't find link to appropriate Codepad page now) :(

There definitely can be even more ways to do this.

Comment: I used user and role n:n relation as example. In your case that will be role and modules n:n relation.